# how to use rtc on android native app

Tags: android, webrtc, kurento

I need some help to use **RTC** on Android.
Actually, we have mount a **KMS** (Kurento Media Server).
The web demo (with websocket node.js) work perfectly. (demo in one 2 one)

> http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/node/tutorial-one2one.html

Globally we have different step:

call register (with an id) > return ok.
Then we use call function, the call send an sdpOffer. > We receive an answer sdp.
And we are connecting (One 2 one with webcam).

The problem on my App:

I’m trying to implements this, on Android in Native application.
I’m starting from project: https://github.com/billyriantono/kurento-android-client

I update the code in SDK version 23.
Stun server : google

> First error:
>   E/Camera: Camera new cameraInitNormal:0

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I don’t understand why i have this error.

> Second error:
>   I receive an sdpAnswer which is the same as sdp offer, is it normal?
>
> Third error:
>   I don't know why i don't see any image

Devices used:

- Huawei P9 Lite
- Samsung Alpha
- Motorola G4

Thk's a lot for your help (quickly if possible, i lost many hair!)